# Add an item to array - reactjs hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add an item to the array. That array was fetched using an API.

but when I click to add the item, it's not updating.

here is my onChange code

```
  const changeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const textName = e.target.value;
    setText(textName);
  };
```

here is my add to array code

```
  const addNewHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const addNewname = {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      name: text
    };

    console.log(addNewname);
    const apiupdate = [...api];
    // apiupdate.concat(addNewname);
    // console.log(apiupdate);
    setApi(apiupdate.concat(addNewname));
    console.log(api);
  };
```

here is where I call that function

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  value={api.Name}
  name="Name"
  onChange={changeHandler}
/>
<Button
  variant="outlined"
  color="primary"
  style={{ margin: "10px" }}
  onClick={addNewHandler}
>
  Add Me
</Button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hooks-swvn0...

Please use this in your local network issue with fetch when using in the sandbox

Comment: In case, if you need the whole code here it is. https://pastebin.com/uG6XcGzY

Comment: Is the issue that `console.log(api)` shows the old version (unupdated) of `api`, or does `api` actually not update when rendered?

Comment: It shows old version.. Then I tried something, it showed new version, but again not rendering

Comment: Your code should work, please make a producible example.

Comment: It is not working... I'll try to add sandbox in a while

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hooks-swvn0 .... pls use this in your local.. network issue with fetch when using in sandbox

Comment: setting state is an async functionality. you cannot log and see state right below it, if you want to see the updated state, log in render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
const addNewHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const addNewname = {
       id: Math.random().toString(),
       nutritionalInformation: {
         calories: 0,
         fat: 0,
         saturatedFat: 0,
         sugars: 0,
         salt: 0
      },
      name: text
    };

    console.log(addNewname);
    const apiupdate = [...api, addNewname];
    // apiupdate.concat(addNewname);
    // console.log(apiupdate);
    setApi(apiupdate);
    console.log(api);
};
```

`[...api, addNewname]` add `addNewname` to end of `api` array and make a new array.

Also, I set `nutritionalInformation` when adding new item.

Comment: Please do refer my full coding. There may be some other things i might have missed

Comment: @LogeshP There are some errors in other parts of your code, I changed my answer and check it. you use `nutritionalInformation' but you never set it.

Comment: I changed my answer. Please check it. @LogeshP

Comment: your code works fine.. but cant we do this without that nutritional information ?

Comment: @LogeshP Yes, you can, You should use guard operator before using it in `TableCell` like this: `<TableCell align="justify">
                  {row.nutritionalInformation && row.nutritionalInformation.calories}
                </TableCell>`